# Before El Camino, has it been established that Jesse Pinkman graduated high school?

Tags: breaking-bad, el-camino-a-breaking-bad-movie

I'm asking in the context of this dialogue in *El Camino* between Walt and Jesse:

> Walt: First step, get your GED, that's no problem.
>   Jesse: What do I need a GED for? I got my diploma.
>   Walt: Oh. Of course, yeah, right. Right, right, right.
>   Jesse: Yo, you were standing right on stage when they handed it to me.
>   Walt: I know, it just slipped my mind.
>   Jesse: I totally graduated high school, dick.

I've watched all of *Breaking Bad* but like Walter White in *El Camino*, I didn't know or forgot that Jesse graduated high school. Before *El Camino*, I've assumed that Jesse was a high school dropout as Walt, in *Breaking Bad*, has repeatedly mentioned Jesse's poor academic performance in high school.

Because of this, while I was watching *Breaking Bad*, I also had a low opinion of Jesse's academic intelligence, and was surprised by this dialogue in *El Camino*, where it was shown that Jesse is actually smart enough to graduate high school. This scene was set at the same time as Season 2 of *Breaking Bad*; if this had been shown in *Breaking Bad*, I would have had a different view of Jesse Pinkman.

Is this the first time in the *Breaking Bad* franchise that it is confirmed to the audience that Jesse graduated high school? If not, in what episode of *Breaking Bad* was it previously made known to the audience?

Comment: _"This scene was set at the same time as Season 2 of Breaking Bad, so if this was shown back in Season 2, I'd have a different view of Jesse Pinkman."_ Why would it specifically need to be shown in season 2? Jesse graduating happens well before the first season begins.

Comment: @Flater I didn't say that the scene specifically needed to be shown in Season 2. Keyword: **if**. It could have been shown in any other season. Maybe except Season 1, because that scene won't make sense chronologically (the diner scene happens within the events of S02E09).

Comment: @T.J.L. I've already edited it.

Comment: I'd say the 5 seasons of Breaking Bad (esp. 1-4) give rather the impression that Jesse failed high school (without specifically mentioning it).

Answer (score 5):

From my memory of the show and a few quick google searches, it doesn't seem like whether or not Jesse graduated was explicitly mentioned in the series.

There's a few places where Walt called Jesse a "drop-out" which would makes the scene in El Camino make a little more sense (Walt assuming Jesse was a dropout the entire time until Jesse corrects him).

Unless someone can find a quote that I'm missing where they discuss it, I think you're correct in assuming that it wasn't mentioned before this movie.